# Vuejs v-on:click not working in v-if

Tags: vue.js

It is strange. I am trying to trigger a method when an element is clicked in the v-for loop. But it does not work when I use v-if or v-show. This is my HTML code sample;

```
 <div class="chosen-drop custom_choices" v-if="showResults"> <!--   -->
            <ul class="chosen-results">
                <li class="active-result level-0 isresult" v-for="City in Results" v-bind:class="{ highlighted: SelectCity.name==City.name }" v-on:click="HandleSelectCity(City)" >{{ City.name }}</li>
            </ul>
 </div>
```

This is my method;

```
            methods: {
                HandleSelectCity: function (City){
                    this.SelectCity = City;
                    this.search_input = City.name;
                }
            },
```

I am using Vuejs 1.0.8

Answer (score 2):

This works as expected for me.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showResults: true,
    Results: [{
        name: 'one'
      },
      {
        name: 'two'
      }
    ],
    SelectCity: null
  },
  methods: {
    HandleSelectCity(City) {
      this.SelectCity = City;
      this.search_input = City.name;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.8/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="chosen-drop custom_choices" v-if="showResults">
  <ul class="chosen-results">
    <li class="active-result level-0 isresult" v-for="City in Results" v-bind:class="{ highlighted: SelectCity.name==City.name }" v-on:click="HandleSelectCity(City)">{{ City.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I solved the problem finally. This was just a conflict between the v-on:blur and  v-on:click

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem. This was just a conflict between the v-on:click and v-on:blur When the element that had v-if was removed the user didn't have any time to click on the element with the v-on:click

I solved the problem by adding a delay.

Comment: Could u give a demo? think you. I dont understand thsi way. I have this problem.